# TextView In TableViewFooter within CollectionView scroll on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have TextView inside a TableView FooterView and that TableView is inside CollectionViewCell. 
How to have the TextView move when pressed. Now Keyboard collapses with the textView. It does not scrolls the TableView up by default.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **TextView move**?

Comment: I mean the view to move up when pressed on TextView. Keyboard collapses with the textview. I assumed by default it should work as its in TableViewcell but its not working.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your IB please?

Comment: is look like?
 `UICollectionView` -> `UICollectionViewCell` -> `UITableView` -> `UITableViewCell` -> `UITextView`

Comment: @SPatel Yes. Please the screenshot.

Comment: Have you taken the reference of your `tableView` inside your `collectionViewCell` subclass?

Comment: @iPeter Yes. I have taken reference.

Comment: Check the answer please!

Comment: @iPeter cannot see. You hv posted the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the reference of the bottom `constraint` of your `tableView` and then change the `constraint constant` to **keyboard height**, then the bottom of your `tableView` as well as the `textView` will come just above the keyboard.

Comment: Im very sorry. I just realised that textView is under TableView Footer and not cell.

Comment: If you have bottom constraint of your tableView then you can change the constraint constant to **keyboard height** then the bottom of your `tableView` will come just above the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. I did it by ur way. Taking bottom constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). It will handle all keyboard events.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use third party library for this.